# Focus and blur component after action on different component in Reagent

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

Here is my Clojurescript code:

```
(def focus-wrapper 
  (with-meta identity
    {:component-did-update #(.focus (dom-node %))}))

(defn solution-input []
  (let [current-char (subscribe [:current-char])
        input (subscribe [:input])]
    [focus-wrapper
      (fn []
        [:input {:type "text"
                 :auto-focus true
                 :value (:value @input)
                 :disabled (:disabled @input)
                 :on-change #(dispatch [:input-value-updated (.-target.value %)])
                 :on-key-press #(when (= 13 (.-which %))
                                  (if (= (.-target.value %) (:solution @current-char))
                                    (dispatch [:right-option-picked])
                                    (dispatch [:wrong-option-picked])))}])]))

(defn quiz [props childrn this]
  (let [current-char (subscribe [:current-char])
        counter (subscribe [:counter])
        feedback (subscribe [:feedback])]
    (fn []
      [:div.panel-container
        [:h2 "Quiz"]
        [:div.counter (str (:correct-guesses @counter) "/" (:total-guesses @counter))]
        [:div.char (:hint @current-char)]
        [solution-input]
        [:div.feedback (when (not= @feedback "off") @feedback)]
        [:button {:type "button"
                 :on-click #(dispatch [:next-char])}
                 "Skip"]
        [:button {:type "button"
                 :on-click #(dispatch [:panel-changed "result"])}
                 "Finish"]])))
```

Notice I am also using re-frame. I am keeping the input state (its value and disabled state) in my app-db and subscribing to them in my component. Therefore, it is easy to force the focus on the component once any of these props change (that is what my focus-wrapper is for).

Nevertheless, I am struggling to find a way to force focus on the input once the skip button is clicked. As far as I am aware, [this is a typical justified](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs) use case for `ref` in React, which seem to work differently in Reagent.

Can someone recommend a way to solve this specific focus management problem in Reagent/re-frame?

Answer (score 1):

I think the use of effects is in order.

```
(reframe/reg-event-fx
    :next-char
    (fn [cofx [_ a]]
        (.focus (.getElementById js/document "text-field-id"))
        {}))


  ...
  [:button {:type "button"
             :on-click #(dispatch [:next-char])}
             "Skip"]
```

Comment: I did not even think about just selecting the dom node, which seems a pretty straightforward alternative in case there is no way to just reference to it.